# Generating graph path from an array with numbers in ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have an undirected graph with 12 nodes. In this method:

```
def generate_paths
  arr = []
  (1..10).each { arr << [rand(12)].product([rand(12)]) }
  arr
end
```

I generate an array like this: `arr = [[3, 12], [8, 12], [0, 3], [0, 5], [0, 10], [7, 9], [5, 5], [4, 9], [5, 12], [0, 1]]` which represents the graph edges.

I would like to find the longest possible path through the graph, such as each edge is used at most once. For given example it would be something like: `arr = [[1, 0], [0, 5], [5, 5], [5, 12], [12, 3], [3, 0], [0, 10]]`

I have seen on a number of sources solutions to this problem by searching the Euler path but written in other programming languages​​. How would I proceed with it in Ruby?

Comment: Can you explain your expected ordering in addition to the example?

Comment: where is `[1,0]` in the unsorted array ?

Comment: @Ruby - This is not sorting, this is path generating over the graph. Please update the question to clarify it.

Comment: @BroiSatse thank you for clarifying the issue corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear at the moment what the goal is.

I'm going to guess that you're trying to get an array of arrays containing random numbers where the second number of any given array is equal to the first number of the next array.

If that's the case, then you can achieve this easily, using `each_cons`, which is short for "each consecutive" and takes an argument of `n` (i.e. number of items).

```
random_numbers = 8.times.map { rand(12) }
# => [1, 0, 5, 5, 12, 3, 0, 10]


random_numbers.each_cons(2).to_a
# => [[1, 0], [0, 5], [5, 5], [5, 12], [12, 3], [3, 0], [0, 10]]
```