# Generating path over the graph Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, sorting, graph-algorithm

I have an undirected graph with 12 nodes and I generate an array like this:

```
arr = [[3, 12], [8, 12], [0, 3], [0, 5], [0, 10], [7, 9], [5, 5], [4, 9], [5, 12], [0, 1]]
```

which represents the graph edges.

I would like to find the longest possible path through the graph, such as each edge is used at most once. For given example it would be something like:

```
arr = [[1, 0], [0, 5], [5, 5], [5, 12], [12, 3], [3, 0], [0, 10]]
```

I have seen on a number of sources solutions to this problem by searching the Euler path but written in other programming languages​​. How would I proceed with it in Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An euler path visits *every* edge *exactly* once, so I guess you do not need that. What I can offer is something like this:

```
def find_path(arr, first_chain = nil, path = [], available = arr.dup)
  edge_idx = available.index do |first, _| 
    first_chain.nil? || first == first_chain
  end
  unless edge_idx
    return path
  end
  edge = available.delete_at(edge_idx)
  path << edge
  find_path(arr, edge.last, path, available)
end

arr = [[0, 5], [3, 0], [5, 5], [1, 0], [0, 10], [5, 12], [12, 3]]

find_path arr
# => [[0, 5], [5, 5], [5, 12], [12, 3], [3, 0], [0, 10]] 

find_path arr, 1
# => [[1, 0], [0, 5], [5, 5], [5, 12], [12, 3], [3, 0], [0, 10]]
```

This algorithm finds *some* path starting with the first element, or any other integer given. It is *not* guaranteed that it uses all elements, or that it is even the longest possible, but it is a path...

---

For a non-directional graph, you need to account that the edge might be reversed:

```
def find_path(arr, first_chain = nil, path = [], available = arr.dup)
  edge_idx = available.index do |edge| 
    first_chain.nil? || edge.include?(first_chain)
  end
  unless edge_idx
    return path
  end
  edge = available.delete_at(edge_idx)
  edge = edge.reverse if first_chain && edge.first != first_chain
  path << edge
  find_path(arr, edge.last, path, available)
end

find_path arr
# => [[0, 5], [5, 5], [5, 12], [12, 3], [3, 0], [0, 1]] 

find_path arr, 1
# => [[1, 0], [0, 5], [5, 5], [5, 12], [12, 3], [3, 0], [0, 10]]
```

---

To find the *longest* path, you need to build *all* possible paths, and select the longest:

```
def find_longest_path(arr, first_chain = nil, available = arr.dup)
  paths = available.each_index.select do |edge_idx| 
    first_chain.nil? || available[edge_idx].include?(first_chain)
  end.map do |edge_idx|
    edge = available[edge_idx]
    edge = edge.reverse if first_chain && edge.first != first_chain
    [edge, *find_longest_path(arr, edge.last, 
                         available[0...edge_idx] + available[edge_idx+1..-1])]
  end
  # a hack to find longest in all reverse paths
  if first_chain.nil? && arr == available
    paths << find_longest_path(arr, nil, arr.map(&:reverse))
  end
  paths.max_by { |path| path.length }
end

arr = [[3, 12], [8, 12], [0, 3], [0, 5], [0, 10], [7, 9], [5, 5], [4, 9], [5, 12], [0, 1]]

find_longest_path arr
# => [[10, 0], [0, 3], [3, 12], [12, 5], [5, 5], [5, 0], [0, 1]] 

find_longest_path arr, 1
# => [[1, 0], [0, 3], [3, 12], [12, 5], [5, 5], [5, 0], [0, 10]]
```

**What this code does?**
Instead of taking the *first* edge that can be used in our path, this algorithm takes *all* the edges that can be used in our path.

For each such edge, it builds a new path which:

1. starts with the selected edge
2. removes the edge from the `available` array
3. continues with the *longest path* available starting from the edge's out vertex (recursion)

This builds a list of all *possible* paths. From this the method returns the *longest* (max by length).

The three lines I marked as `# hack` are because when the `first_chain` is `nil` the algorithm finds the longest path starting with *any non reversed edge*. To support reversed edges I run it twice - the second time with all edges reversed.

This is *not* an implementation of a known algorithm but a simple brute-force implementation, which might not very well be most efficient, simple or beautiful, but it should put you in the right direction. You might find more information about working with Graphs in ruby [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26943&seqNum=6)

Comment: nice method for certain but based on his initial arr it returns `[[3,12]]` as the full path. I think the issue lies in the array generation as your method works great with an array that meets the requirement of the algorithm.

Comment: @engineersmnky - the requirements are not clear, maybe his allow to change the direction of the edge. I might add that capability tomorrow if I'll feel like it...

Comment: Actually it seems you have answered the question based on his [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272571/generating-graph-path-from-an-array-with-numbers-in-ruby) which was closed he is looking for the longest path. Which your methods does perfectly.

Comment: @Uri Agassi I learn Ruby and still not very well versed in the language syntax and algorithms. Could you show what the solution looks finding Euler path for all elements of the array and not just the first? I understand that I need to add edge_idh in a loop?

Comment: @Ruby - What I did is _not_ an Euler's path implementation, but a straight forward brute-force path finding. You seem to have edited the question completely, which is unfortunate, since that is _not_ the question I aimed to answer. I can add a version of the code which find the _longest_ path, but not according to any known algorithm (AFAIK)

Comment: @Uri Agassi - just in your algorithm is computed as I can see the chain constructed from the first value in the array, if you build a chain of all the values​​, it will be possible to allocate the longest for the entire array. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Ruby yes, since it is not finding the _longest_ path, but rather _a_ path.

Comment: @Ruby - with my update `find_longest_path arr` should find the longest path in your array (trying all elements of the array to find it).

Comment: @Ruby - I've added an explanation - enjoy

Comment: @Uri Agassi - thank you very much for your time, you helped me a lot in learning this language.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you although there might be better methods

```
def generate_array
  a = []
  b2 = nil
  10.times do 
    b1,b2 = [b2 || rand(12),rand(12)]
    a << [b1,b2]
  end
  a
end
generate_array
#=> [[0, 4], [4, 4], [4, 11], [11, 4], [4, 8], [8, 11], [11, 4], [4, 2], [2, 6], [6, 0]]
```

Also just a note based on your given output `rand(12)` will never return `12` because the upper limit is set using a 0 index so the largest number to be returned is 11

Comment: Apparently you have misunderstood the question, meaning that you need to generate a path over the graph, ie a chain already generated in the array.

Comment: @Ruby your question is unclear at this point the path generation includes elements not in the original array. Seems possibly someone has done what you are looking for [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26943&seqNum=6)